# How to force SonarLint to scan jsx files?

Tags: reactjs, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I am using *Webstorm 2017.1.3*. I have [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/) plugin with sonar configuration downloaded from our sonar server.

The linting works flawlessly on javascript files with extension `.js`. However, no linting is performed on `.jsx` or `.scss` files.

Since we have quality profiles for almost every kind of source file, I need to see the problems immediately, not after I push the data to repository.

Currently, when I need to lint a JSX file, I have to first rename it to `.js`, run the linter and then rename it back.

Is there any way to force SonarLint to run on all files instead of the preset file extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this can be achieved by using the property:

```
sonar.javascript.file.suffixes: .js, .jsx
```